# Как отменить автозаполнение input при нажатии на него?

Tags: php, bootstrap, laravel, php7

Использую bootstrap-3 Datepicker. Есть табличка, в шапке есть два input-a для фильтрации строк. Изначально они пустые, но  при нажатии на них, во время всплытия формочки календаря, input заполняется текущей датой(временем).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я может не хочу фильтровать по дате - просто так нажал.

```
$('.calendar').datetimepicker({...});
```

HTML

```
<input class="calendar tbs-row" type="text" title="Дата от" data-attribute="from"><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

По стандарту `UI` так не должно быть, вы можете просто использовать `onShow` и очистить инпут после открытия календаря:

```
 $(calendar).datepicker({
    onShow: function(picker, inst) {
    $(this).val('');
    }
```

Должна помочь данная методика.

Так же вы можете проверить в параметрах `datetimepicker`, возможно там используется `beforeShow` или `onShow` где в  `callback` вставлено действие автозаполнения инпута.

Comment: Помогло. Для _Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker_ нужно закомментировать строчку
    `setValue(currentMoment);`